# How to get ID number of SQLite row using another field

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I'm currently developing an Android app, in which the user can create objects, view all of the objects in a programmatically-created 2x[n] scrollview activity, and delete these objects.

My issue arises when I delete. Since I'm programmatically creating `AllStreaks`, my method of using i to get the ID of the SQLite row I want to edit quickly falls apart. For example, if I have 2 objects, delete the second, add a third object, and then go to delete the third, my program will still be looking for the second object (which is already gone) since I have to programmatically create (and therefore reset) `AllStreaks`.

I'm still new to using SQLite, and I'm unsure how I'd get the correct ID of an SQLite table based on a programmatically-created activity.

**AllStreaks.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_streaks);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("carter.streakly", MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    //createAllStreaks();
}

public void showMessage(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}

public static AllStreaks getInstance(){
    return allStreaks;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Use other Buttons");
    builder.setMessage("Please use the on-screen back buttons");
    builder.show();
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    createAllStreaks();
}

private void createAllStreaks(){
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.all_streak_table);
    res = db.getAllData();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder returnDiag = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        returnDiag.setTitle("Empty");
        returnDiag.setMessage("Go add some streaks, then come here!");
        returnDiag.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AllStreaks.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        returnDiag.show();
    }

    allStreaks = this;

    streakArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    int counter = prefs.getInt("allCounter", 0);
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        streakArrayList.add(new Streak(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(0)), res.getString(1), res.getString(2), res.getString(3), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(4))));
        counter++;
        editor.putInt("allCounter", prefs.getInt("allCounter",0) + 1);
    }

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    btnParams.setMargins(200, 30, 80, 30);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tvParams.setMargins(100, 0, 0, 0);

    try{
        int startingPoint = prefs.getInt("idCount", 0);
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        editor.putInt("idCount", 0);
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i < res.getCount()) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            mTableRow = new TableRow(this);
            mTableLayout.addView(mTableRow);
        }

        ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        mTableRow.addView(ll);

        final Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("" + streakArrayList.get(i).getDaysKept());
        btn.setId(prefs.getInt("idCount", 0));

        int idCount = prefs.getInt("idCount", 0) + 1;
        editor.putInt("idCount", idCount).commit();

        if(streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory() == null){
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Health")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_health_bubble));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Mental")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_mental_button));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Personal")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_personal_bubble));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Professional")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_professional_bubble));
        }
        else if (streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityCategory().equals("Social")) {
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.category_social_bubble));
        }
        else{
            btn.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button));
        }

        btn.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AllStreaks.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_complete_or_view);
                dialog.show();

                final TextView dialogMessage = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.select_complete_or_view);
                final Button yesButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yes_completed);
                final Button viewButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.view_streak);

                yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        String passNameString = Integer.toString(btn.getId());
                        String activityName = streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getActivityName();
                        String activityCategory = streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getActivityCategory();
                        int newNum = (streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getDaysKept()) + 1;

                        boolean isUpdated = db.updateData(passNameString, activityName, activityCategory, newNum);
                        if (isUpdated == true){
                            Log.d("carter.streakly", passNameString + Integer.toString(newNum));
                            finish();
                            startActivity(getIntent());
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                        else{
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(AllStreaks.this, "Data not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        }
                    }
                });

                viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        editor.putInt("currButtonID", btn.getId()+1).commit();
                        editor.putString("currButtonActivityName", streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getActivityName()).commit();
                        editor.putString("currButtonActivityCategory", streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getActivityCategory()).commit();
                        editor.putInt("currButtonDaysKept", streakArrayList.get(btn.getId()).getDaysKept()).commit();
                        Log.d("carter.streakly", btn.getId() + "" + prefs.getInt("currButtonID", 999) + prefs.getString("currButtonActivityName", "") + prefs.getString("currButtonActivityCategory", "") +
                                prefs.getInt("currButtonDaysKept", 999));

                        Intent intent = new Intent(AllStreaks.this, EnlargedActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        ll.addView(btn);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(streakArrayList.get(i).getActivityName());
        tv.setId(i);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        tv.setTextSize(20);
        tv.setLayoutParams(tvParams);
        ll.addView(tv);

        i++;
    }

    streakCount = db.getAllData().getCount();

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("carter.streakly", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    backHomeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back_home_button);

    backHomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AllStreaks.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

**EditStreak**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_streak);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("carter.streakly", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    res = db.getAllData();
    if(res.getCount() ==0) {
        //show message
        showMessage("Error", "Nothing found");
        return;
    }

    /*
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString("doneList", "");
    final ArrayList<Integer> doneList = gson.fromJson(json, ArrayList.class);
    if (doneList == null){
        doneList.add(0);
    }*/

    editStreak = this;

    final int passName = prefs.getInt("passName", 0);
    final String passNameString = Integer.toString(passName);
    Log.d("carter.streakly", passNameString);

    streakArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    streakIcon = new EditText(this);
    doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_done_button);
    editBackground = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.edit_background);
    deleteStreakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_streak_buton);

    streakIcon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_streak_name);
    categoryIcon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_streak_category);
    streakDaysKept = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_days_kept);
    streakIcon.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    streakIcon.setTextSize(30);

    //res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("ID"));

    ArrayList doneList = new ArrayList();

    int i = 0;
    while (res.moveToNext()){
        streakArrayList.add(new Streak(Integer.parseInt(res.getString(0)), res.getString(1), res.getString(2), res.getString(3), Integer.parseInt(res.getString(4))));
    }

    streakIcon.setText(prefs.getString("currButtonActivityName", ""));
    streakDaysKept.setText(Integer.toString(prefs.getInt("currButtonDaysKept", 0)));
    categoryIcon.setText(prefs.getString("currButtonActivityCategory", ""));

    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editor.putString("currButtonActivityName", streakIcon.getText().toString()).commit();
            editor.putString("currButtonActivityCategory", categoryIcon.getText().toString()).commit();
            editor.putInt("currButtonDaysKept", Integer.parseInt(streakDaysKept.getText().toString().trim())).commit();
            String updateID = Integer.toString(prefs.getInt("currButtonID", 0));
            String updateName = prefs.getString("currButtonActivityName", "");
            String updateCategory = prefs.getString("currButtonActivityCategory", "");
            int updateDaysKept = prefs.getInt("currButtonDaysKept", 0);
            boolean isUpdated = db.updateData(updateID, updateName, updateCategory, updateDaysKept);
            if (isUpdated == true){
                Log.d("carter.streakly", "AFTER SUCCESS: ID: " + prefs.getInt("currButtonID", 0) + " Name: " + prefs.getString("currButtonActivityName", "") + " Category: " +
                    prefs.getString("currButtonActivityCategory", "") + " Days Kept: " + prefs.getInt("currButtonDaysKept", 9));
                Intent intent = new Intent(EditStreak.this, EnlargedActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(EditStreak.this, "Data not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });

    deleteStreakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String deleteID = Integer.toString(prefs.getInt("currButtonID", 0));
            int num = prefs.getInt("currButtonID", 0);
            Log.d("carter.streakly", "COUNT: " + res.getCount());
            checkDoneList(num);
            //int doneListAdder = prefs.getInt("currButtonID", 0);
            //Log.d("DELETE ID: ", "" + doneListAdder);
            //doneList.add(doneListAdder);
            //addIntToDoneList(doneList, doneListAdder);
            //checkDoneList(doneList, (prefs.getInt("currButtonID", 0))-1);
            Log.d("carter.streakly", "BEFORE DELETION: " + deleteID);
            Integer deletedRows = db.deleteData(deleteID);
            if (deletedRows > 0){
                editor.putInt(""+deleteID, Integer.parseInt(deleteID)).commit();
                Log.d("carter.streakly", "AFTER DELETION: " + deleteID);
                //streakArrayList.remove(passName);
                /*
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(doneList);
                editor.putString("doneList", json).commit();*/
                db.vacuum();
                Intent intent = new Intent(EditStreak.this, AllStreaks.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(EditStreak.this,"Data not Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
}

private int checkDoneList(int deleteNum){
    for (int j = deleteNum; j < res.getCount(); j++){
        if (streakArrayList.get(j).getActivityName().equals("") || streakArrayList.get(j).getActivityName() == null){
            deleteNum++;
        }
    }
    return deleteNum;
}

private void addIntToDoneList(ArrayList<Integer> doneList, int doneListAdder){
    doneList.add(doneListAdder);
}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

public void showMessage(String title, String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
}

public static EditStreak getInstance(){
    return editStreak;
}
}
```